# How can I copy text from Links (webpage) to the console?

Tags: console, lfs, links

I have been building a Linux From Scratch system and I have installed the Links web browser on it, which I am running in graphical mode via DirectFB (I have not yet installed the X Window System). I am wondering if there is a way that I can copy text from a Links webpage running in one tty, to a console (Bash) running in another tty?

I know text can be copied between two ttys with GPM; however, I can't find a way to do it from Links. In text mode, I seem to be unable to highlight text with the cursor; in graphical mode, I can highlight text, but it doesn't copy to the console with the middle mouse button, like it does in GPM.

It would be very helpful for building further LFS packages, if I could copy-paste text from a web browser to the console.

Comment: Use [screen](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/screen)

Comment: @IporSircer ok, I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `screen` and `tmux` both have a "copy" feature, after using CTRL+A "ESC" (`screen`) or CTRL+B "ESC" (`tmux`). That way it is no longer relevant which program you're trying to copy from.

Answer (score 3):

Try to hold down shift when you are trying to copy and paste inside of Links.

Comment: I tried to hold down shift, nothing happened - cut and paste not possible.

Comment: shift + left  doubleclick or left drag

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to copy by block the link using mouse and then press SHIFT+G to copy into clipboard.
You could verify the copied link in Notepad or other Text Editor.
Then copy to other console.